# Program in C , working with 3 digits but not working with 5 digits

Tags: c, factorial

`145` = sum of `1! + 4! + 5!`. I need to write a program in C, that finds the 5 digit numbers that have this property.

I have written the code successfully for the 3 digits. I used the same code for 5 digits, but it cant find any number.

I would like to help me with my solution, in order for me to see where am I wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int factorial(int n);

main() {
    int pin[5];

    int q = 1;
    int w = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int t = 0;

    int result = 0;

    int sum = 0;

    for (q = 1; q <= 9; q++) {
        for (w = 0; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (e = 0; e <= 9; e++) {
                for (r = 0; r <= 9; r++) {
                    for (t = 0; t <= 9; t++) {
                        pin[0] = q;
                        pin[1] = w;
                        pin[2] = e;
                        pin[3] = r;
                        pin[4] = t;

                        int factq = factorial(q);
                        int factw = factorial(w);
                        int facte = factorial(e);
                        int factr = factorial(r);                                                                       
                        int factt = factorial(t);

                        sum = factq + factw + facte + factr + factt;                
                        result = 10000 * q + 1000 * w + 100 * e + 10 * r + t * 1;

                        if (sum == result)
                            printf("ok");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int factorial(int n) {
    int y;
    if (n == 1) {
        y = 1;
    } else if (n == 0)
        y = 0;
    else {
        y = n * factorial(n - 1);
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe it just does not finish

Comment: The exercise, insists that there is JUST ONE 5 digit number that meets the "code". First i tried and succesfully write the code that worked for 3 digit number and gave me the 145, as the excersise mentioned! So i just added 2 more digits and i expected it to work. It does not return anything. Any help would by great. I'm trying 4 hours :/

Comment: @Hogan, what do you mean my friend?

Comment: He probably means that you've got for-loops nested 5-deep calling recursive functions.  Your program is doing a lot of work and might not finish in the timescale you expect it to.

Comment: The growth in time is non-linear moving from 3-5 does not take 80% more time-- it will probably take 10000% more time.  So it just has not finished.

Comment: The program finishes. It returns nothing. Shouldn't it return "ok"? Instead , i get Process exited with return value 1814400

Comment: @Hogan Even with 5 nested loops, there are only 10000 total iterations.  The time to do that is trivial.

Comment: https://ideone.com/WdJSfa

Comment: On the topic of performance, rather than calculating the factorials of the digits `[0-9]` ~500,000 times, consider calculating each numeral once and putting it in a look-up table.  40 bytes is a small price to pay to avoid so much recalculation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `factorial` function doesn't return a value in all cases:

```
int factorial (int n) {
    int y;
    if (n==1) {
        y = 1;
    }
    else 
        if (n==0)
            y = 0;
        else {
            y = n * factorial(n-1);
            return y;
        }
}
```

It only returns a value when it makes a recursive call.  The base cases don't return anything.  Failing to return a value from a function and then attempting to use that value invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Move the `return` statement to the bottom of the function so it gets called in all cases.  Also the value of `0!` is 1, not 0.

```
int factorial (int n) {
    int y;
    if (n<=1)
        y = 1;
    else 
        y = n * factorial(n-1);
    return y;
}
```

Also, when you find the target value you probably want to print it:

```
printf("ok: %d\n", result);
```

Comment: Thank you guys SO MUCH! Not only solved the exercise, but i got valuable information about my syntax generally! Appreciated.
By the way, number is 40585 :)

Comment: @dimcon Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer]9https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for reminding me. This was my first post. Still trying to get familiar with. :)

Answer (score 0):

dbush's answer is accurate in pointing out why your code didn't work.  This is an alternative solution to reduce the amount of calculation done by your program by not re-calculating the factorial of each numeral every step of the way.  The way your program currently works, it winds up being around 500,000 calls to the factorial function from your nested loop, and then in turn recursively calls the function on average 4ish times for each call from the nested loop, so that's around 2 million calls to `factorial`.  The more digits you tack on, the faster that number grows and more expensive it gets.  To avoid all these recalculations, you can create a `Look-up table` that stores the factorial of the numerals `[0-9]` and just looks them up as needed.

You can calculate these values ahead of time and initialize your LUT with these values, but if hypothetically you wanted them to be calculated by the program because this is a programming assignment where you can't cut out such a step, it is still pretty trivial to populate the LUT.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void populate_lut(uint32_t *lut);

int main(void) {
   // lut is an array holding the factorials of numerals 0-9
   uint32_t lut[10];
   populate_lut(lut);
    for (uint8_t q = 1; q <= 9; q++) {
        for (uint8_t w = 0; w <= 9; w++) {
            for (uint8_t e = 0; e <= 9; e++) {
                for (uint8_t r = 0; r <= 9; r++) {
                    for (uint8_t t = 0; t <= 9; t++) {
                        // now instead of calculating these factorials, just look them up in the look-up table
                        uint32_t sum = lut[q] + lut[w] + lut[e] + lut[r] + lut[t];                
                        uint32_t result = 10000 * q + 1000 * w + 100 * e + 10 * r + t * 1;

                        if (sum == result) {
                            printf("Solution: %" PRIu32 "\n", result);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// populate your lookup table with the factorials of digits 0-9
void populate_lut(uint32_t *lut) {
   lut[0] = 1;
   lut[1] = 1;
   for(uint8_t i = 2; i < 10; ++i) {
      lut[i] = lut[i-1] * i;
   }
}
```